# Design pattern - Writing an API wrapper library (typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, inheritance, composition

facing a bit of a problem trying to come up with a way to code this. Let me start this off by saying this is not my forte, nor have I tried something like this before.

Aim: creating a wrapper API library for a client. It should expose a way/class to instantiate the lib with a basePath and then expose namespaced objects/classes with methods on them that call into the internal API, so the consumer only needs to pass in whatever data may be required for each API call for simplicity, and so we can generically handle some things like errors.

I know what I have here won't work - but it's mostly to get an idea of what I'm hoping to achieve.

My questions are things like

- should the basePath possibly be set from a static method and basePath just be a property?
- how else could this be composed, so we can share methods and the access to the basePath, but not need to instantiate it each time?

I appreciate all the help and suggestions.

```
abstract class Base { 
    constructor(private basePath: string = '') {}
    async get<T>(endpoint: string, config?: RequestInit | undefined): Promise<T> { 
        const response = await fetch(this.basePath + endpoint, config);
        return response.json();
    }
    // ... other methods that would be available  
}

// Exported to the consumer for ease of use. Others could be `Comments.postNewComment({user, data})`
class Posts extends Base {
  getAllPosts() {
    return this.get<PostsData>('/posts')
  }
}

// In the main index file for lib, it would export all the classes with available API methods (such as Posts, Auth, Comments etc) that the consumer would be able to use.
// Issue comes up when creating an instance of these because it would require the basePath again
export { Posts: new Posts(), Comments: new Comments() }; 

// Ideal usage: Main file of the app:
import LibName from 'lib-name'
new LibName({ basePath: 'api.whatever' }) // Left out re: brevity, but would be the class where we instantiate the basePath, and anything else

// In other locations through the app, be able to call the various methods from different sections (Auth.login, Comments.addNewComment etc)
import { Posts } from 'lib-name';
Posts.getAllPosts();
```

I was following [this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-build-an-api-client-library-in-javascript-665df869bdd5) to begin with, but the final example of this exposes ALL methods under one export (DevToClient.X), whereas I am hoping to have them namespaced off their appropriate parent object.

Comment: No, you should not use a singleton. If you want them namespaced, use a structure like `const lib = new Lib({ basePath:…}); const posts = lib.posts(); posts.getAll()`. The `Posts` class should probably not inherit from `Base`, but instead use composition, and the `Base.prototype.posts` methods should instantiate it passing the current endpoint.

Comment: @Bergi when you say the Posts class should use composition, could you possibly explain or drop an example in on how this would be achieved, I'm struggling with the mental model, but agree with your points.

Comment: I mean you'd have a `class Endpoint { constructor(basePath) {…} posts() { return new Posts(this) } }` and `class Posts { constructor(endpoint) { … } getAll() { return this.endpoint.get('/posts') } }`

Comment: @Bergi appreciate the help! This is really close to what I'm after. Is there a way that from the lib we could still only expose the instantiated versions of the classes like posts, so we don't need to call `const lib = new Lib({}); const post = lib.posts`, as it will be across different files, and ideally would just be imported from the lib itself.

Comment: Yes, but that would be bad api design. You should be able to instantiate different endpoints in the same application. If it will be used across different files, just import the parts from your own module in which you instantiate the library, instead of importing them from the library module.

Answer (score 2):

Why not make an instantiable class for an `Endpoint` that depends on the type of the object `T`?

```
class Endpoint<T extends {id: string}, Creatable = T> { 
    constructor(private endpointPath: string) {}
    async get(id: string, config?: RequestInit | undefined): Promise<T> { 
        const response = await fetch(this.endpointPath + '/' + id, config);
        return response.json();
    }
    // stubs of sample methods
    async getAll( someFilters?: any ): Promise<T[]> {}
    async update(changes: Partial<T> & {id: string}): Promise<T> {}
    async createNew( object: Creatable ): Promise<T> {}
}
```

I'm also adding this second optional argument `Creatable` because it's normal for a create request to not include every property of the created object.  For example `id` and `date` are probably set by the server.

We would not export the `Endpoint` class, instead we would create instances for the different types and export them.

```
export const Posts = new Endpoint<PostObject>('/posts');
export const Comments = new Endpoint<Comments>('/comments');
```

You can use it like this:

```
import {Posts} from 'some-lib'

const post = Posts.get("321"); // Promise<PostObject>

// the arguments depend on your partuicular api structure
const latest = Posts.getAll({limit: 10, sort: 'date'}); // Promise<PostObject[]>

const updated = Posts.update({id: "123", title: "New Title"}); // Promise<PostObject>
```

If you want to support more advanced configurations that differ between endpoints for things like validation, that's where you would use composition.  The `Endpoint` can accept some sort of `config` object or class in the constructor.